# Python switching browser focus with selenium

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to open up multiple browsers with different sites, and navigate those said browsers. I have written the code to open up the initial browser and navigate freely. However, when I open up the second tab and command it to get a new site, it changes the first browser (initial Safari "tab") to the new site.

Example Shortened code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import 
Keys

browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://twitter.com')

browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').
send_keys(Keys.Command+'t')   


browser.get('https://facebook.com')
```

At this point the "twitter tab (first tab)' changes to facebook, while the second tab, which is the one visibly in front, stays vacant.

How do I get the web-driver to control the second tab?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between browser tabs/windows as follows:

```
for handle in browser.window_handles:
    browser.switch_to_window(handle)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try to wait until second tab has handles

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.Command+'t')   

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
    lambda b: len(b.window_handles) != 1
)
# switch to second tab
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1]) # or [-1] for latest tab
browser.get('https://facebook.com')
```

Comment: browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[1]) # or [-1] for latest tab. # A variation of this line seemed to do the trick.